# How can I perform matching on an “encrypted- fingerprint feature matrix” using Fully Homomorphic Encryption?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, reference-request

I am doing a finger-print authentication process. The feature-extraction using minutiae has been done and I get an `N x 6` matrix, where the 6 columns are {$x_i$ ,$y_i$, crossing number of the $i$th minutiae, orientation of $i_{th}$ minutiae, rest 2 columns are not used for matching}. The first two are `(x,y)` co-ordinates of the ith minutiae point detected. The crossing number detects the type of minutiae `(ridge=1,bifurcation=3)`.

I want to encrypt this matrix. Perform matching in the encrypted domain and send the result back in encrypted form (like a [homomorphic-encryption](/questions/tagged/homomorphic-encryption)).

Is there code or idea for doing this? Please help.

The following is an example of the simple matching program code in C (without any encryption)…

The feature matrices which are got as output after the feature extraction are `t1` and `t2`. The values can be seen assigned to matrix `t1` and `t2` in the program. These are the feature vectors of `101_1.tif` and `101_2.tif` from FVC2002 Database. (images of same person). It gives output as similarity score of `0.7` (out of 1), which means the images match.

Another thing observed from the 80 images database is that on applying the feature extraction the maximum value for "N" (the number of features) is **82**. That is, the row size is max. 82 and column size is always 6 (fixed). Here is the program (in C for matching):

```
#include stdio.h
#include math.h


float t1[26][6]= {216.0000,46.0000, 3.0000, 0.5030,0, 1.0000,190.0000,49.0000, 1.0000, 3.5827,0, 1.0000,146.0000,64.0000, 1.0000, 3.2684,0, 1.0000,247.0000,80.0000, 1.0000, 0.7002,0, 1.0000,173.0000,86.0000, 1.0000, 0.3666,0, 1.0000,302.0000,93.0000, 1.0000, 0.8372,0, 1.0000,176.0000,127.0000, 3.0000, 0.2761,0, 1.0000,227.0000,131.0000, 3.0000, 0.5634,0, 1.0000,164.0000,135.0000, 1.0000, 3.3159,0, 1.0000,117.0000,140.0000, 1.0000, 5.7642,0, 1.0000,216.0000,169.0000, 1.0000, 0.7320,0, 1.0000,256.0000,170.0000, 3.0000, 3.8934,0, 1.0000,196.0000,181.0000, 1.0000, 3.7386,0, 1.0000,176.0000,187.0000, 3.0000, 0.4613,0, 1.0000,151.0000,195.0000, 1.0000, 5.7175,0, 1.0000,285.0000,215.0000, 3.0000, 0.7886,0, 1.0000,227.0000,218.0000, 1.0000, 0.8161,0, 1.0000,152.0000,219.0000, 1.0000, 2.2884,0, 1.0000,169.0000,233.0000, 1.0000, 4.1407,0, 1.0000,147.0000,242.0000, 1.0000, 4.6064,0, 1.0000,186.0000,250.0000, 1.0000, 4.1676,0, 1.0000,240.0000,332.0000, 1.0000, 0.4986,0, 1.0000,165.0000,227.0000, 5.0000,0,0, 1.0000,72.0000,360.0000, 7.0000,0,1.0000,1.0000,324.0000,12.0000, 7.0000,0, 1.0000, 1.0000,120.0000,312.0000, 7.0000,0, 1.0000, 1.0000};


float t2[19][6]= {190.0000,45.0000,3.0000,0.5896,0,1.0000
                  ,139.0000,46.0000,3.0000,0.1600,0,1.0000
                  ,126.0000,54.0000,1.0000,3.3025,0,1.0000
                  ,79.0000,64.0000,1.0000,5.7130,0,1.0000
                  ,181.0000,83.0000,1.0000,0.6658,0,1.0000
                  ,219.0000,84.0000,3.0000,3.9261,0,1.0000
                  ,159.0000,98.0000,1.0000,3.7340,0,1.0000
                  ,136.0000,110.0000,1.0000,0.2556,0,1.0000
                  ,118.0000,115.0000,1.0000,5.8276,0,1.0000
                  ,248.0000,130.0000,3.0000,0.8766,0,1.0000
                  ,192.0000,134.0000,1.0000,0.8088,0,1.0000
                  ,117.0000,137.0000,1.0000,2.3575,0,1.0000
                  ,132.0000,150.0000,3.0000,2.4106,0,1.0000
                  ,111.0000,164.0000,1.0000,4.6623,0,1.0000
                  ,149.0000,169.0000,1.0000,4.1655,0,1.0000
                  ,129.0000,148.0000,5.0000,0,0,1.0000
                  ,60.0000,264.0000,7.0000,0,1.0000,1.0000
                  ,276.0000,264.0000,7.0000,0,1.0000,1.0000
                  ,84.0000,264.0000,7.0000,0,1.0000,1.0000
                 };

float t3[30][4],t4[20][4],tnew[30][4];
void transform(float t1[26][6],int i,int flag);
void transform2(float t4[20][4],float thref);
float score(float x1[22][4],float x2[15][4]);

main()
{
    float sm=0,S=0;
    int i,j,a,i1,j1;
    printf("Matching Program\n\n");

    for(i=0; i<22; i++)
    {
        transform(t1,i,1);
        for(j=0; j<15; j++)
        {
            if(t1[i][2]==t2[j][2])
            {
                transform(t2,j,2);
                for(a=-5; a<6; a++)
                {
                    transform2(t4,(a*3.1416/180));
                    sm=score(t3,tnew);
                    if(S<sm)
                    {
                        S=sm;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(S>0.4) printf("Match");
    else printf("Mismatch");
}

//COORDINATION TRANSFORM FUNCTION
void transform(float t1[26][6],int i,int flag)
{
    float xref,yref,thref;
    int k,l,j,c,count,i1,j1;
    float b[3][1],t[5][5];
    xref=t1[i][0];
    yref=t1[i][1];
    thref=t1[i][3];
    float r[3][3]= {cos(thref),sin(thref),0,-sin(thref),cos(thref),0,0,0,1};
    if(flag==1)
        count=22;
    else if(flag==2)
        count=15;
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        b[0][0]=t1[i][0]-xref;
        b[1][0]=t1[i][1]-yref;
        b[2][0]=t1[i][3]-thref;
        for(j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            for(k=0; k<3; k++)
            {
                t[j][k]=0;
                for(c=0; c<3; c++)
                    t[j][k]=t[j][k]+(r[j][c]*b[c][k]);
            }
        }
        if(flag==1)
        {
            for(c=0; c<3; c++)
            {
                t3[i][c]=t[c][0];
            }
            t3[i][3]=t1[i][2];
        }
        if(flag==2)
        {
            for(c=0; c<3; c++)
            {
                t4[i][c]=t[c][0];
            }
            t4[i][3]=t1[i][2];
        }
    }
}

//COORDINATION TRANSFORM FUNCTION2
void transform2(float t4[20][4],float thref)
{
    float r[4][4]= {cos(thref),sin(thref),0,0,-sin(thref),cos(thref),0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},b[4][1],t[5][5];
    int k,l,i,j,c,i1,j1;
    for(i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
            b[j][0]=t4[i][j];
        b[2][0]=b[2][0]-thref;
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            for(k=0; k<4; k++)
            {
                t[j][k]=0;
                for(c=0; c<4; c++)
                    t[j][k]=t[j][k]+(r[j][c]*b[c][k]);
            }
        }
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            tnew[i][j]=t[j][0];
        }
    }
}

//Transformed Minutiae Matching Score
float score(float x1[22][4],float x2[15][4])
{
    int i,j,i1,j1;
    float n,thres,thres_theta,found,dx,dy,sm;
    float dtheta,d;
    n=0;
    thres=15;
    thres_theta=14;
    for(i=0; i<22; i++)
    {
        found=0;
        j=0;
        while((found==0)&&(j<15))
        {
            dx=x1[i][0]-x2[j][0];
            dy=x1[i][1]-x2[j][1];
            d=sqrt(pow(dx,2)+pow(dy,2));
            if(d<thres)
            {
                dtheta=(abs(x1[i][2]-x2[j][2]))*180/3.1416;
                if(dtheta>(360-dtheta))
                    dtheta=360-dtheta;
                if(dtheta<thres_theta)
                {
                    n=n+1;
                    found=1;
                }
            }
            j=j+1;
        }
    }
    sm=sqrt(pow(n,2)/(22*15));
    return sm;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't read over your code entirely, but a quick glance at it tells me you will have a hard time simply "porting"it to something like [helib](https://github.com/shaih/HElib). First, I don't think helib has native support for floating point. Second, functions like sqrt, sin, cos, etc might take a fair amount of work to get going in something like helib even if you had floating point math.

That said, in theory you should be able to perform matching on encrypted fingerprint matrices using homomorphic encryption. The application of HE, however, is still not at a point where it will be super easy and practical to do so.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. . Well i also thought so.. but since I am not an expert i needed to confirm it.. I have just started with helib on github... but it is using c++ which i am not that fond of.. i have tested something like: multiplication, addition, subtraction on cipher texts.. which worked well.. now i am trying with matrices.. but, i couldn't find a way to input the matrix into to methods(encode, encrypt methods) in the "EncryptedArray" class.. can you help me out...

Answer (score 2):

> Is there code or idea for doing this?

As you did not specify what research you have done, or what you already know, I can merely guess.

In case you haven’t done so yet, you could check on:

- [A privacy-compliant fingerprint recognition system based on homomorphic encryption and fingercode template](http://goo.gl/HJScvF)
- [Minutiae Matching with Privacy Protection Based on the Combination of Garbled Circuit and Homomorphic Encryption](http://goo.gl/TZ2Sdv)
- [A Keypoint Descriptor for Alignment-Free Fingerprint Matching](http://goo.gl/IcvEwQ)

and last but not least

- [Privacy–Preserving Processing of Biometric Templates by Homomorphic Encryption](http://goo.gl/APrsUC)

Depending on the research you have (or haven’t) already done, each of them might provide helpful pointers to you.

I hope you’ll understand that I won’t be throwing in code… the source you’re providing doesn’t show any effort of any encryption implementation yet, and I’m surely not planning to code it all up for you as that would be a bit too much and take it a bit too far for an answer. After all, this isn’t GitHub or something… (But, I definitely would like to echo [@mikeazo, who already pointed you to potential portability issues](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/16380/12164).)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply... I had read the research papers mentioned before starting the work. .  but they use a different technique for feature extraction and matching.. whereas I am using another technique which I coded above (just aligning w.r.t the core point and calculating the euclidean distance). . i needed to know whether it is possible to covert the code into a homomorphic format..

Comment: @Tintumon007 I had a feeling you might have read them, I just wasn’t sure so I didn’t want to miss out on at least mentioning them. As for the practical (coding) side of things… it can be done, but it takes *a whole lot of fiddling* to make all parts fit (yet, [diving into that would be more on-topic at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)). Anyway, I obviously wasn’t as helpful as I wished I could have been – so please don’t thank me for providing nothing usable to you. Oh well, at least I did throw in my good intentions and an upvote on your question. Erm… welcome to Crypto.SE btw.! ;)

Comment: @Tintumon007 Ugh, just noticed [you’ve already been there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23819776/2432317). (A little hint related to that: watch out not to cross-post the same question to different sites of the StackExchange network because such cross-posts tend to get closed pretty quickly around here. Instead, [moderators♦](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) can migrate questions to other sites if it makes sense.)